# What's the meaning if someone says you are ridiculously cute

Tags: adjectives

Meaning of ridiculously cute. It is in positive or in negative sense??

Comment: We can't read minds, unfortunately. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRaj Was it a girl?? ;p

Answer (score 17):

It's a common term here in England and is positive. It is basically being used to mean 'extremely'. It's informal and can precede many compliments.

- Ridiculously cute
- Ridiculously clever
- Ridiculously talented

Comment: 'ridiculously ugly'? - probably OT!

Comment: Same in American English.

Comment: I should've said it adds emphasis, so yes with a negative remark the emphasis is to make it worse